# Objective C not presenting argument labels for Swift convenience init

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, methods, initialization

I have a UIBarButtonItem subclass, "NavBarButtonItem", defined in Swift 3.0 but am not sure if I've set up the convenience initializer properly.  This initializer seems works fine in other Swift classes:

```
let nextBarButtonItem = NavBarButtonItem.init(self, "Next", #selector(pressedNextButton))
```

However, in Obj-C, Xcode presents me with the following (it's missing argument labels):

```
self.nextButton = [NavBarButtonItem alloc] init:<#(id<NavBarButtonDelegate> _Nonnull)#> :<#(NSString * _Nonnull)#> :<#(SEL _Nonnull)#>
```

and I've completed it with:

```
self.nextButton = [[NavBarButtonItem alloc] init:rvc :2 :@"Next" :@selector(doneButtonTapped:)];
```

I've not set up initializers in Swift before so suspect that there might be something wrong but the app compiles.  Here's the Swift subclass:

**MyViewController.swift**

```
// this file contains other classes that precede subclass NavBarButtonItem
..
@objc protocol NavBarButtonDelegate {
    func pressedNextButton()
}

@objc class NavBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem
{
    private var delegate: NavBarButtonDelegate?

    init(_ delegate: NavBarButtonDelegate){
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    convenience init(_ delegate: NavBarButtonDelegate, _ title: String, _ selector: Selector)
    {
        self.init(delegate, wtfProperty)
        self.title = title
        self.action = selector
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't call `init()` directly, bur rather just `let nextBarButtonItem = NavBarButtonItem(...)`. Also, in Objective-C, the class is `UIBarButtonItem` and you initialize it like this: `UIBarButtonItem *nextBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWith...: target:... action:...];`, check at the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibarbuttonitem?language=objc

Comment: You initialization in Swift should probably be: `let nextBarButtonItem = UINavBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextButtonTapped))`

Comment: There isn't any confusion on how to initialize UIBarButtonItem or whether or not I should use .init() or call it directly.  These aren't the issues.  The problem is that I may not be properly setting up the convenience initializer for my Swift subclass.  Any thoughts on that front?  Thx in advance.

Comment: You have to use labels in the Swift method. The _ are the missing labels.

Comment: You're exactly right, Willeke.  I removed the underscores from the line `convenience init(_ delegate: NavBarButtonDelegate, _ title: String, _ selector: Selector)` which fixed the prob.  If you want to post the answer, I'll accept.  Thanks!